# Mobile SDK (IAP, Notifications, Native UI)

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, mobile, sdk

Im looking for a mobile SDK that has the following for iOS and Android (BB and Win Phone are bonuses):

-In-App Purchases
-Notifications
-Native UI
-Camera
-HTTP (need to get info from different websites)

Preferably just have to write all of this once and it work on all platforms (optimistic I think)...

What are the frameworks that support this? I have looked at RhoStudio which is what I plan on using but would love alternatives as I am not overly familiar with Ruby (but will learn it if it's the best option).

Comment: I work in a Windows environment also... can compile or build on a Mac if needed but prefer to work on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [NSBasic App Studio](http://www.nsbasic.com/app/) and Phonegap Build. It seems to do what you want, and it works on Windows. With Phonegap Build you can build for iOS (developer account needed), as well as Android, Windows Phone, Blackberry, WebOS, and Symbian. I personally have used it before and it's quite good. You can get a free trial, and the full version is $99.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need I am just confirming it does In-App Purchases and Notifications, can't find a good feature list or a matrix.

Comment: @EricTeller It does In-App Purchases - you can use PayPal or, for a native iOS App, [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/InAppPurchaseManager). See [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nsbasic-app/message/6450) for more info. Note that if you use the GitHub plugin for iOS, you can't use the Phonegap Build online service - instead, you have to use Phonegap with Xcode on a Mac (still very easy) to compile.

Comment: @EricTeller You can also get "compass, camera, contacts, files and notifications" with Phonegap (see [this PR release](http://www.nsbasic.com/app/pr/pr.110209.htm)).

Answer (score 0):

What about Sencha touch? I don't know if this is what you are looking for so just a suggestion.

Comment: It sounds to me that he wants to use all of the native features... As far as I know (and I may be wrong), Sencha Touch only does UI...

Comment: Ya I looked at Sencha they don't do In-App Purchases :(